# Can Squid server be configured to change the port the of the web request?

Tags: proxy, squid

I'd like to make a test version of my website that runs on the same server, but is served by a different port. I'd like to be able to access it by turning on a browser proxy, that I'm hoping I can configure it so the client can access the server though the same domain and 443 port, but have the proxy switch to the test port in the background so as far as the browser is concerned the port and domain are exactly the same

Would I be able to create a such a proxy with Squid? I'm seeing similar stuff that can be set up in Squid.conf but not this in particular. This would be on Debian linux server.

Comment: Why bother with Squid? Your web server itself can handle this sort of thing, e.g. with a cookie.

Comment: Sounds good, is there an actual feature in Apache that coukld change the root directory depending on this cookie? What other than a cookie could trigger it?

Comment: A query string, but you probably don't want to do that. And Apache? I dunno about that. You probably should be using nginx.

Comment: I can switch, but I have zero experience with nginx, any chance you could link to the setting I'd need to play with to do it with a cookie? Thanks!

Comment: You can use a `map` in nginx to set variables for almost anything you want, for instance a document root or the URL of your backend web app.